# Select Article which has ALL tags (via habtm relation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, tags

I has Article model that has_and_belongs_to_many Tag.

I want to find articles that has tags specified, eg tags = ["tag1, "tag2", "tag"3]

It would be good to have all in sql query. (Postgresql used)

It looks like it will be good to take advantage using Postgresql arrays.

Currently, i'm looking into this approach:

```
select "articles".*, 
(
  select array(
    select tags.name from tags
    inner join articles_tags on articles_tags.tag_id = tags.id and articles_tags.article_id = articles.id
  )
) as tags
FROM "articles"
```

I'm trying to do tags && ARRAY[?] and pass tags but it doesnt work, because 'tags is not a column'.

Maybe you can recommend elegant rails way solution.

UPD

Looks like this sql makes what needed, but it looks not very Rails friendly:

```
select articles.*
from articles 
where articles.id in (
  select t.id
  from (
    select articles.id, array_agg(articles_tags.tag_id) as tag_ids
    from articles
    inner join articles_tags on articles_tags.article_id = articles.id
    group by articles.id
  ) as t
  where t.tag_ids @> array[2,3]
)
```

Is there any way to make it Rails way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
required_tags = ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]

Article.joins(:tags)
       .where(tags: { name: required_tags })
       .group('articles.id')
       .having('count(*) = ?', required_tags.count)
```

What it does is:

- Get all articles that have tags
- which contain one of the required tags
- Group them, so that we have for example a group of 3 when the article has the tags "tag1", "tag2" and "tag3", or just a group of 2 when the article has the tags "tag1", "tag2" and "tag4".
- Then only take those groups with as many members as specified in our required tags array.

There could be better ways to achieve what you want, but that is really the only solution I could think of at the moment.

Comment: It should work. I did a quick test on my data and it returned the correct results.

Comment: But it can give wrong result, eg if Article tags are ["tag1", "tag4", "tag5"] it will still return this Article.

Comment: No it should not. It requires to have all of the specified tags.

Comment: Can't agree: 
where(tags: { name: required_tags }) is 'name in ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')' that is name = 'tag1' or name = 'tag2' or name = 'tag3'. So it will get all Articles that has 'tag1' or 'tag2' or 'tag3' and have 3 tags in total. But it should get only articles that have 'tag1' and 'tag2' and 'tag3'.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Have you tested it?

Comment: Please see prev comment, i described problem there.

Comment: Yes we get all for the single tags first. Then we group them and see if the group contains the correct amount of specified tags. It's nothing special

Comment: Actually, you know, it looks like working...
Give me some time to test it properly...

Comment: I edited the answer to explain it a little more, since there were some misunderstandings yesterday. Hope it helps you.